# Update web table dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, uitableview, user-interface

I had a requirement, I will be getting the data at run-time from xml and this data needs to get updated in a table on html page.

Conditions:

1. If there is not table available on the page then create a table and update
2. If there is a table in the page update the new data to the table

Comment: And is that data retrieval process one time? Or the API gets called after specific time interval?

Comment: Our design has an XML file, it will be updated on timely basis with some information. So, html also designed with auto-refresh feature or we may add refresh button.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, It is XML not json. The data might look like <root><id>1</id><name>ABC</name><id>2</id><name>ABC1</name><id>3</id><name>ABC3</name></root>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using AJAX by calling your JavaScript function after a specific period of time, create a table first when you get your first data and after that, you can just append rows to that table.

You can check [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) for JavaScript timing events.